# Why does my variable work in a test statement, but not in a case statement until I use echo to read it into itself?

Tags: bash, switch-statement, string-substitution

I have a line with a comment.  I use parameter substitution to condition the line into a variable "source".  A test statement shows that the value of source is "Simple:", but the case statement can't match it.  If I use command substitution to "source=$(echo $source)", test says it matches, like before, and the case statement works now.  Am I missing something fundamental, should I not use parameter substitution to do this, or is this weird?  Bash version: GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).  Thanks for taking a look.

Piping the line to sed with echo works as expected.  If no parameter substitution is performed on a variable, case works as expected. Example: line="Simple:" and case $line in ... no issues.

```
#!/bin/bash

line="Simple: #comment and space to be removed"
source=${line//#*}
source=${source//^[[:space:]]*}
source=${source//*[[:space:]]$}

[[ $source =~ 'Simple:' ]] && echo -e "\n1st test match" || echo -e "\nno 1st test match"

case $source in
    'Simple:')  
        ops="Simple"
        echo -e "\n1st try case match.  Ops is $ops"
    ;;
    *)
        echo -e "\nno natch in 1st case"
    ;;
esac

source=$(echo $source)

[[ $source =~ 'Simple:' ]] && echo -e "\n2nd test match" || echo -e "\nno 2nd test match"

case $source in
    'Simple:')  
        ops="Simple"
        echo -e "\n2nd try case match.  Ops is $ops"
    ;;
    *)
        echo -e "\nno match 2nd case"
    ;;
esac
```

I expect "Simple:" would match in the first case statement, but it doesn't until I run "source=$(echo $source)".

Comment: `set -x` makes the shell print what it thinks each command is as it executes them, which can be a great help debugging things like this.

Comment: `source=${line//#*}` is not doing what you think it is doing...

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I've been running my scripts with "#!/bin/bash  -xv" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from `man bash`:

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>
> Pattern substitution. The `pattern` is expanded to produce a pattern **just as in pathname expansion**, Parameter is expanded and the longest match of `pattern` against its value is replaced with `string`. ...

That means, these lines:

```
source=${source//^[[:space:]]*}
source=${source//*[[:space:]]$}
```

do nothing at all, `^` and `$` doesn't work in pathname expansion; the `pattern` is [not a regex](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html). `source=$(echo $source)` makes it work because since `$source` is not in double-quotes, its value undergoes [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) and the space at the end gets lost.

The proper way of doing this using [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is:

```
source=${line%%#*}
source=${source#${source%%[^[:space:]]*}}
source=${source%${source##*[^[:space:]]}}
```

Comment: Also, the reason `[[ $source =~ 'Simple:' ]]` was matching is that it does a *substring* search (because it isn't anchored). Actually, using `=~` here is weird, since it does regex matching, but then single-quoting the pattern string suppresses all regex syntax making it just a string (substring) match. Use the `=` test for plain equality.

Comment: I was definitely missing something fundamental, but this is pointing in the right direction. I ran the above lines in a script with line: "    Simple Simple:    #Comment" to test, and the results were exactly what I was trying to achieve.  1st line removed comments, 2nd line removed preceding spaces, and 3rd removed spaces from the end.  The space between "Simple Simple:" was preserved.  Thank you for the links in the answer too.  "Simple: #comment" ran through the test and case statements exactly as expected with your corrections.